# API Gateway V2 slowness on initial request

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I've got an API Gateway V2 (Protocol:HTTP) style endpoint, it simply makes a request to my Lambda function and gives me the response.  I've noticed that if I make no request for about 10 minutes or so, that on a new request it's going WAY slower than the requests afterwards.  It's the same function that does the same thing every time so I'm not sure why this is happening, has anyone else ever had this and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that your Lambda function has to be started before it can handle requests.

This is also called **cold start**.

Starting a new instance of your Lambda does take some time. Once it is started it will serve several requests. At some point in time the AWS Lambda service is going to shutdown your Lambda function. For example when there has not been any traffic for a while.

That's where your observation is coming from:

> I've noticed that if I make no request for about 10 minutes or so, that on a new request it's going WAY slower than the requests afterwards.

When there are no instances of your Lambda running and a new requests is coming in, the AWS Lambda service needs to instantiate a "fresh" instance of your Lambda.

You could read this blog which touches this topic:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/

Comment: thanks ill check it out

Comment: yeah this seems like it is why, this particular Lambda function relies on some libraries that are kind of large and that takes a moment for Lambda to load it, not sure how to reduce it though because they are dependencies for what's being used storage in "node_modules" folder in the root Lambda function directory.  I tried moving it in the code but it still seems to autoload those dependencies

Comment: Based on your comment I figure you are using NodeJS. We are "building" our NodeJS Lambdas with [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io). The output is a single file that is minified etc. It might help, but usually cold start takes long because you are doing requests to SSM, S3 etc.

Comment: Yeah I was just researching and it looks like I need to slim down the node_modules folder.  I have other functions using AWS api none of them go this slow ever, definitely the size of my node_modules tho

Comment: so based on the current situation, i've decided to create 2 seperate lambda functions and isolate the large function and use it as little as possible, as modifying the node_modules is going to be very difficult it is very delicate and was hard getting it working to begin with

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept the answer.